# Cannot subscript a value of type [String : AnyObject] with an argument of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey

Tags: ios, swift5

```
func imagePickerController(_picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String == kUTTypeImage as String) {
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }

}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) { self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you likely upgraded the project but the main issue is your wrong method declaration.

it should be:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

---

Noticed how info is not a [String:Any] dictionary but a [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any] dictionary

It WORKED because the actual method call coming from the ObjC/C implementation from UIKit doesnt much care what your type says.

Also under the hood String == UIImagePickerController.InfoKey BUT thats only lowlevel. as far as swift typing is concerned, thats not really exchangable